# freeradius rlm_python tagged attributes

Tags: python, freeradius, attributes, mod-python

I've created python auth module.
When trying to perform testing with radtest reply is:

```
    User-Password = "testing123"
    NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
    NAS-Port = 0
    Message-Authenticator = 0x00
    Cleartext-Password = "testing123"
Received Access-Accept Id 188 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 0.0.0.0:0 length 48
    ERX-Service-Activate:0 = "srs-local-ipoe"
```

As you can see the ERX-Service-Activate has only one zero tagged attribute.

But radiusd -X shows me another output:

```
authorize - 'reply:ERX-Service-Activate:1' = 'srs-local-ipoe'
authorize - 'reply:ERX-Service-Activate:2' = 'srs-localnet-ipoe(110000)'
authorize - 'reply:ERX-Service-Activate:3' = 'srs-foreignnet-ipoe(110000,110000)'
authorize - 'config:Auth-Type' = 'Accept'
authorize - 'config:Cleartext-Password' = 'testing123'
```

How to get all ERX-Service-Activate tagged attributes.

Python construct reply:

```
reply = (('Framed-IP-Address', str(client.ipv4)),
             ('ERX-Service-Activate:1', 'srs-local-ipoe'),
             ('ERX-Service-Activate:2',
              'srs-localnet-ipoe(%s)' % str(client.s_localnet)),
             ('ERX-Service-Activate:3',
              'srs-foreign-ipoe(%s,%s)' % (str(client.s_foreign),
                                          str(client.s_localnet))),)
```

P.S. Reply in Wireshark has only one ERX-Service-Activate attribute too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed in freeradius version 3.0.17

Also reply should be modified a little bit:

> ```
>   reply = (('Framed-IP-Address', str(client.ipv4)),
>          ('ERX-Service-Activate:1', 'srs-local-ipoe'),
>          ('ERX-Service-Activate:2', '+=',
>           'srs-localnet-ipoe(%s)' % str(client.s_localnet)),
>          ('ERX-Service-Activate:3', '+=',
>           'srs-foreign-ipoe(%s,%s)' % (str(client.s_foreign),
>                                       str(client.s_localnet))),)
> ```